# Creating TABLE AS in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm creating a table in Oracle PLSQL which needs to be similar to an old table in the same database. I have already created the new table and it is fine. However, the created table will only display the data as of the created time since it was copied from the old table. How do I ensure that the newly created table's data is always synchronized with the old table?

Comment: you want two tables sharing same data? That could be done wither by using triggers or by not having second table at all - use a view for second option?

Comment: look at a view or a materialized view?

Comment: What is the ultimate goal? Why do you need two identical tables in the same schema with the exact same set of rows? For historical or testing reason, or maybe for something else?

Comment: Hi, thank you. I would prefer to use a trigger in that case. Using view in my case might not be so applicable since I need to perform some testing on the new table.

Comment: Then have a look at `MERGE` command. It is not a good idea to mess old table with trigger only for testing purposes.

Comment: @Anonymous If you are just testing, then I would suggest that you have a stable set of rows do you can validate and repeat your test.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with periodic refreshes, I would use a materialized view instead (with materialized view log for refreshing just the new.changed rows).
If you need exact up to the transaction data, then I would use Golden Gate replication [or you can use the poor mans replication as previously suggested by other].

Answer (score 0):

A materialized view with fast refresh option should solve this